# How do get good looking justified paragraphs?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, text-formatting

Avoid ugly white space in justified formatted content (i.e. lines should be spread to fill the whole width).

If I have this paragraph (one paragraph, using <kbd>Shift+Enter</kbd> to split it into several short lines):

```
a b c
c d e
f g h
```

and select "Justify" as formatting, I see this on the screen:

```
a                          b                             c
c                         d                              e
f g h
```

How do I get word to stop justifying short lines/treat all lines like the last one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just enter a `tab` (<kbd>tab</kbd>) directly before line break (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>).

A bit longer story: http://word.tips.net/T001324_Using_Manual_Line_Breaks_with_Justified_Paragraphs.html

Comment: Excellent trick, thanks! Now I need to figure out how make pandoc pass the tab to the Word document ;-)